# simplifying a query in order to improve execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i would like to know whether the following query is optimized?

```
 select 
  SUM(payments.paid_amt) as paid_amt, 
  SUM(payments.copay_amt) as copay_amt,
  SUM(payments.CO_INSURANCE_AMT) as co_ins_amt,
  payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP as payor_group,
  DATEPART(MM,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE) as load_month,
  DATEPART(yyyy,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE) as load_year

  from 
  [F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_monthly] payments

  join D_PAYOR payor
  on payor.PAYOR_ID=payments.PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID

  join D_PAYOR_GROUP payor_group
  on payor.PAYOR_GROUP_KEY=payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP_KEY

  join F_ACCESSION_DAILY accession
  on accession.ACCESSION_ID=payments.ACCESSION_ID

  group by  payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP, DATEPART(MM,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE),
  DATEPART(yyyy,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE)
```

it has been executing for about 1.5 hours now. there are no indexes on any tables yet!

every table has around 10,000,000 rows.

is there any way i can simplify this query to improve execution time?

thank you so much for your guidance and time.

Comment: yes absolutely, but before i put those in, i would like to know whether my query can be improved

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you're doing the nested select, as opposed to just doing all of the grouping simultaneously.  Making it a single query may or may not help.

Comment: Asking whether a query can be improved "before" putting in indexes is silly.  Adding indexes is an essential part of improving query performance, and there are no meaningful changes you can make that would retain their value after adding an index.

Comment: You are defining your CTE already summarized, why are you grouping again on your `SELECT`?

Comment: @Lamak thank you for the commment. yes, it should be summarized! but for some reason it does not come out summarized

Comment: In the definition of your CTE, you should group by `payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP,DATEPART(MM,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE),DATEPART(yyyy,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE)` instead of `payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE`

Comment: Something is wrong here. Even though all tables are unindexed the query should complete in seconds or minutes by means of hash joins. SQL Server can handle this just fine (it's just a basic data warehouse style query). Screaming for indices misses the point of this question.

Comment: @usr you're saying it should still complete in a few seconds or minutes? but it does not, what is wrong here?

Comment: @Артём Царионов, can you post the execution plan as a screenshot? I can usually tell what the problem is by looking at the plan.

Comment: I disagree with @usr on that if you have all those tables with approximately 10 million rows on each one and no indexes this could run in seconds. But you should post your execution plan

Comment: @Lamak I intentionally said seconds *or minutes*. The run time of big hash joins is mostly a function of the size of the data in bytes, not rows. So 10m rows means nothing by itself.

Comment: the query in the question and the query in the chosen answer are the same... right?  i am assuming the question query was updated to match the answer?  that sucks because now it's really hard for me to learn anything from the question w/o the original stuff....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a With at all?

```
  select 
  SUM(payments.paid_amt) as paid_amt, 
  SUM(payments.copay_amt) as copay_amt,
  SUM(payments.CO_INSURANCE_AMT) as co_ins_amt,
  payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP as payor_group,
  DATEPART(MM,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE) as load_month,
  DATEPART(yyyy,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE) as load_year

  from 
  [F_PAYOR_PAYMENTS_monthly] payments

  join D_PAYOR payor
  on payor.PAYOR_ID=payments.PAYMENT_PAYOR_ID

  join D_PAYOR_GROUP payor_group
  on payor.PAYOR_GROUP_KEY=payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP_KEY

  join F_ACCESSION_MONTHLY accession
  on accession.ACCESSION_ID=payments.ACCESSION_ID

  group by  payor_group.PAYOR_GROUP, DATEPART(MM,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE),
  DATEPART(yyyy,accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE)
```

Answer (score 2):

No indexes on tables with 10m rows each is most likely going to kill your performance. Any query that runs for an hour is not optimized and needs attention. Most queries should run in a few seconds.

I would suggest starting out adding indexes on your key columns (payor.payor_id,, payments.payment_payor_id, payor.payor_group_key, paygor_group.payor_group_key, payments.accession_id). After that try running your query in SSMS with the "Include actual Execution Plan" option enabled (under Query file menu). Run your query and it will suggest additional indexes to you, which you should consider applying.

Are your tables under a lot of load from other processes? Do they accept a lot of incoming data?

Before you put any focus on changing your query syntax or doing any "other" optimization, you need to apply indexes. After you get the indexes put in and the query performing at a normal rate (<1min times) you can look at additional index tuning or adding table/query hints where needed.

Comment: thank you. what does WITH NO LOCK do? we accept incoming data only once per day on a LOAD process

Comment: Please don't give nolock advise like this. nolock is rarely needed and dangerous. Also, it is not the problem here.

Comment: `WITH (READPAST)` may be a better idea. It avoids locks (like `WITH (NOLOCK)`) and doesn't cause dirty reads (*unlike* `WITH (NOLOCK)`).

Comment: Edited response, I misread your question. Work on your indexes first!

Comment: READPAST is just as dangerous. Don't slap hints on the query without reason. READPAST means you are guaranteed wrong results in case your query hits any incompatible lock. Do you really recommend doing that?

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, you're grouping by `accession.XIFIN_LOAD_DATE` instead of the Month/Year of that date, which is why you need the second group by.  If you fix that then it's just one query. This should improve the performance but indexes will be the biggest help.